# Cut text outline of rectangle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

This is the result i'd like to have:
[image]

So it's a text, with a rectangle exactly the size of the text, than translating up for 50% of the text height and to the right with 50% of the first letter width.

I achieved this in Photoshop by creating the text outline, duplicate the rectangle, delete the text outline from one of the rectangles (1), than selecting the outline of the other rectangle (2) and delete it from the text. And at last deleting rectangle (2).

Many steps for something which, to me seems, should be much easier.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to which would be a much easier workflow? I guess Illustrator would be the right tool for the job, I found something about pathfinder but didn't get the above result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy as a pie: There are two parts of the artwork. One, the text which is subtracted by the shape. And two, the shape that is subtracted by the text. This is the only way I can think of to this very easily.

**Step 1**

Get your text and shape ready. **Make sure you turn the text into outlines/curves.** Copy both text and shape and paste it on front or back(**CTRL+C** ===> **CTRL+F**ront or **CTRL+B**ack). Now you have two pieces of shape and text on top of each other.

> [image]

**Step 2**

Using your selection tool, select both text and shape that is visibly on top of the layer. Then hit minus front. Now here in the above image the shape is on front of the text which means it will be subtracted from the text. **(Make sure to make the text into a compound path 1st before hitting minus front so the letters are grouped into one object.(CTRL+8))** This should be the result. You can see here that the outlines of the text is only up to the border of the shape.

> [image]

**Step 3**

Now we have our 1st part of the artwork done. Now hide the subtracted artwork from the layers as so it won't be moved or lock it. Now assuming you have your duplicated text and shape we will now build the shape subtracted by the text. Now what to do is bring the text IN FRONT of the shape layer (remember? minus front - because we want to subtract the text TO the shape.) Hit minus front after. Now un-hide the 1st part that we did and put some color.

*And tadaa!*

> [image]

**Hope this is clear enough to understand! it's pretty easy to this, doable in 30 seconds!**

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop:

- Start with black background, white text.
- Select your rectangle.
- Invert colors.
- colorize the image, or use the black/white as a mask on another layer.